# Why does http://stackexchange.com only list 9 of the public beta sites?

Tags: bug, status-completed, beta-phase

From the [Area 51 progress tab](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress), it is apparent that there are 13 current beta sites, 12 of which are public.

https://stackexchange.com/ links to SO, SF, and SU, MSO, Stack apps, and the 9 oldest  public beta sites.

This appears to be a bug - the list should include every public beta, and has not been updated to include the new three in the past 6 days.

The complete list is present at the bottom of every beta site.

If this is not a bug, please change the tag to status-bydesign and answer the question which logically follows:
*What is the criteria for a public beta to become a member of the list at http://stackexchange.com?*

The listed sites are older, have more questions/amswers, and have more users than the three (Tex, GIS, and Home Improvement) which are not.  However, there is no clear distinction between the two groups.

Comment: They really should just be using their API to pull that information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a new version of StackExchange.com coming very soon.  We jumped the gun a little bit by pushing the new link to it before the new site is out.  The new version will pull the list of sites from the API appropriately.